# In Perl, how to use 'defined' function on elements of two-dimensional array?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, defined, autovivification

I am trying to check if an element is defined, using [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function in Perl.

Code :

```
$mylist[0][0]="wqeqwe";
$mylist[0][1]="afasf";
$mylist[1][0]="lkkjh";

print scalar(@mylist), "\n";

if (defined($mylist[2][0])){print "TRUE\n";}

print scalar(@mylist), "\n";
```

Output

```
2
3
```

Before using [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function, there were two elements in first dimension of `@myarray`. After using [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function, the number of elements increase to 3.

How to use [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function with out adding new elements ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First check that the first-level reference exists.

```
if ( defined($mylist[2]) && defined($mylist[2][0]) ) {
    print "TRUE\n";
}
```

What you've encountered is called [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification): under some circumstances, Perl creates complex data structures when you use them as if they already existed.

Answer (score 5):

It's interesting to note that there's a non-core pragma called [autovivification](http://p3rl.org/autovivification), and that if you run your code under `no autovivification;` your problem will go away.

Answer (score 3):

When you refer to `$mylist[2][0]`, perl's [autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) creates the array element `$mylist[2]`.

To prevent this, you can check this element first:

```
if ( (defined $mylist[2]) && (defined $mylist[2][0]) )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
defined($mylist[2][0])
```

is equivalent to

```
defined($mylist[2]->[0])
```

which is short for

```
defined( ( $mylist[2] //= [] )->[0])
```

due to autovivification. You can disable autovivification using the [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) pragma.

```
no autovivificatoin;
if (defined($mylist[2][0]))
```

Or you can avoid evaluating code that would trigger it.

```
if (defined($mylist[2]) && defined($mylist[2][0]))
```

Comment: It really sucks that the spell checker doesn't recognise "autovivification" because it's so easy to misspell! :)

Comment: Just curious : If `defined(mylist[2][0])` adds new element by [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification), why isn't print statement after `defined(mylist[2][0])` returning `TRUE` ?

Comment: @user1029725 `defined($mylist[2][0])` creates the `$mylist[2]` element. `$mylist[2][0]` is still undefined. You can check to make sure with Data::Dumper if you want to.

Comment: The first element of the empty array created through autovivification is not defined, since it doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 2):

Actually because it's autovivification, you can check it easily with Data::Dumper, before and after using defined.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @mylist;

$mylist[0][0]="wqeqwe";
$mylist[0][1]="afasf";
$mylist[1][0]="lkkjh";

print Dumper(@mylist);
```

Output before

```
$VAR1 = ['wqeqwe', 'afasf'];
$VAR2 = [ 'lkkjh'];


print Dumper(@mylist);
```

Output after

```
$VAR1 = [ 'wqeqwe','afasf' ];
$VAR2 = ['lkkjh'];
$VAR3 = [];
```

Comment: You should use a reference as argument to `Dumper`, e.g. `print Dumper \@mylist`. It will keep the array structure intact and make it more readable. (You should also format your answer so we can see the structure.)